# Understanding Basis Transformation in Linear Maps and Matrix Representation

Tags: linear-transformations

I am trying to find the matrix representation of a linear map $\varphi:V\to V$ in a new basis $e_1' = e_1 + e_2$ and $e_2' = -2e_1 - e_2$, given that the original basis is $e_1, e_2$ ($e_1, e_2$ is a basis of $V$). The linear map is defined as:

$$
\varphi(\epsilon_1 e_1 + \epsilon_2 e_2) = \epsilon_1 e_1 + (-\epsilon_1 + 2\epsilon_2)e_2
$$

When attempting to find $\varphi(e_1')$ and $\varphi(e_2')$, I initially considered the following:

$$
\varphi(e_1') = \varphi(1.e_1+1.e_2)= e_1 + e_2 \quad \text{and} \quad \varphi(e_2') = \varphi(-2e_1-1.e_2) = -e_1 - 3e_2
$$

With this choice, I constructed the matrix representation as $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & -1 \\ 1 & -3 \end{bmatrix}$ in the basis $e_1', e_2'$. However, this doesn't seem to be correct.

I acknowledge that my question might be quite basic, but I am struggling to understand why my approach is incorrect and how to properly determine the matrix representation in the new basis. Any insights or explanations would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If
$$
\varphi(\epsilon_1 e_1 + \epsilon_2 e_2) = \epsilon_1 e_1 + (-\epsilon_1 + 2\epsilon_2)e_2
$$
and $e^\prime_1=e_1+e_2$ and $e^\prime_2=-2e_1-e_2$, then
$$\varphi(e^\prime_1)=e_1+e_2 \ \ ; \ \ \varphi(e^\prime_2)=-2e_1;$$
Since
$$e_1=-e^\prime_1-e^\prime_2 \ \ ; \ \ e_2=2e^\prime_1+e^\prime_2,$$
we have
$$\varphi(e^\prime_1)=e_1^\prime \ \ ; \ \ \varphi(e^\prime_2)=2e_1^\prime+2e_2^\prime.$$
Therefore, the matrix of $\varphi$ with respect to the basis $\{e^\prime_1,e^\prime_2\}$ is given by
$$\mathcal M(\varphi)=\begin{pmatrix}1&2\\0&2\end{pmatrix}.$$